# How to stop scanning a vector's indexes?

Tags: java

To practice I am trying to make my own vector class. One of the methods I want to create is a length method.

I tried to do a `while` loop to scan through the vector's indexes.

```
package ejercicios.cap.pkg1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vector {

    static int[] creaVector(int i) {
        int vector[] = new int[i];
        int l;
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (l = 0; l < i; l++) {
            vector[i] = num.nextInt();
        }
        return vector;
    }

    static int dimVector(int[] vector) {
        int dim = 0;
        while (vector[dim] != null) {
            dim += 1;
        }
        return dim;
    }
}
```

So I haven't executed this. But NetBeans shows the error: "Incomparable types int and " and "Unnecessary test for null - the expression is never null".

Comment: Why not just return vector.length? Arrays, such as int[], have a length property. As for the error, ints can never take a null value. Integer, the wrapper class for int, can take a null value, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incomparable types int and **what**? If it is vector, in java you cannot compare primitive types and objects.

Edit:
Null is an object.
Int is a primitive.
You cannot implicitly compare the two in Java.

Comment: and <null> sorry

Comment: Null is an object in Java. Int is a primitive type. You can not compare them in Java unless you cast one into the other. This is what I what I have written above but I will augment it to reflect Null.